# How to get keyboardColor in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

[TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/keyboardAppearance.html) can set `keyboardAppearance` between `Brightness.light` / `Brightness.dark`, how to get the keyboard color while `light` / `dart` ?

Comment: Maybe you should add a `ios` tag, this seems to be platform specific question.

Comment: Hope if there is a solution in flutter way applies in both `iOS` and `Android`